# Font Awesome icon in React

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I was unable to get Font Awesome icon working when using string as value for icon parameter.

This working:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

 <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
```

However this does not:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

<FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee" />
```

And according to this [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react) it should.
But I am new to React so may be missing something.

Using javascript. Project created with react cli.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-metismenu": "^1.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "rsuite": "^4.8.8",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

By "not working" I mean that icon is not visible on the page and console have an error: "Could not find icon {prefix: "fas", iconName: "coffee"}"

Comment: First, please clarify whether you are using JS or TypeScript. Then please elaborate on what you mean by "not working". Thirdly, please share the version of `react-fontawesome` you're using (from `package.json`). Thanks!

Comment: I updated information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to import `library` like this: `import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'`

Then add the icon(s) you wish to use.

```
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(faCoffee /*, faCheckSquare, etc*/)
```

After this, you should be able to use the icon as "coffee". If you are not adding the icons to the library, they will not be included in the bundle, hence the error.

Comment: That works. Thank you.
However it means that for each icon to use I need to add it to that Library object.
Is there any trick to add all of them at once? Or that is bad idea?
For now I think I will stick with importing font awesome css styles and using <i>